# WPF CheckBox multiBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I need to bind a checkBox to TWO property and I think that i have to use `multiBindings`

so far i have this, but this doesn't work.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="FilterAll" Content="All">
 <CheckBox.IsChecked>
  <MultiBinding>
     <Binding Path="SearchEngineCompassLogView.FilterSearch.IsFilterAllEnable"
            Source="{StaticResource CompassLogView}">
     </Binding>

     <Binding Path="SearchEngineCompassLogView.FilterSearch.IsFilterVisible"
             Source="{StaticResource CoreServiceLogView}">
     </Binding>
  </MultiBinding>
 </CheckBox.IsChecked>
</CheckBox>
```

is this even possible with MultiBinding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use MultiBinding.  And as ethicallogics said, you must use a converter to do the actual logic of the parameters (whether you want to do AND, OR, whatever.  You can see a little more about those [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/809/wpf-tutorial-using-multibindings)

I'm not sure what you are trying to affect on your checkbox,  but in the end it will look something like this.

```
<CheckBox.IsChecked>
   <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBoolConverter}">
        <Binding Path="SearchEngineCompassLogView.FilterSearch.IsFilterAllEnable" Source="{StaticResource CompassLogView}"/>
        <Binding Path="SearchEngineCompassLogView.FilterSearch.IsFilterVisible"
             Source="{StaticResource CoreServiceLogView}"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</CheckBox.IsChecked>
```

There is also another way to do this as well, which I sometimes find useful. It's called DataTriggers.  If you've done any work with Styles and Templates then you may have seen them before.  Here is an example based on your question:

```
<CheckBox>
  <CheckBox.Style>
     <Style TargetType={x:Type CheckBox}>
        <Style.Triggers>
          <MultiDataTrigger>
             <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Condition Binding="{Binding Path="SearchEngineCompassLogView.FilterSearch.IsFilterAllEnable" Source="{StaticResource CompassLogView}" Value="True"/>
                  <Condition Binding="{Binding Path="SearchEngineCompassLogView.FilterSearch.IsFilterVisible" Source="{StaticResource CoreServiceLogView}" Value="True"/>
              </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
              <Setter Property="CheckBox.IsChecked" Value="True"/>
          </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
  </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must specify converter in MultiBinding.[Multibinding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328978/Introduction-to-multi-binding-and-multi-value-conv)